# Why i am getting NullPointerException when accessing a member of Array of objects?

Tags: java, arrays, class, object, nullpointerexception

This is where i am getting error

```
Student[] student = new Student[10];

System.out.println(" Test : " + student[2].RollNo);
```

But i do not get error when

```
Student student = new Student();

System.out.println(" Test : " + student.RollNo);
```

Error only shows up when i am creating array of objects.

Comment: Because you have not assigned any Objects to you array

Comment: `student[2]` is `null`

Comment: The call "new array" creates the array, but all its slots are null initially.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko but how? how to not make it null?

Comment: @user3861350 `student[2] = new Student();` (or do it in a loop)

Comment: @user3861350, `student[2] = new Student()`

Answer (score 0):

You have created an array with 10 slots that can contain Student object.
You have not, however, put a student into the third slot hence the NPE

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: student[2] = new Student()